# name not defined and 'int' object not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I have this given code and when I run the doctest, it gave me 2 errors:

- always_roll..strategy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'score' and 'opponent_score'
- name 'strategy' is not defined
- 'int' object not callable (when set default value of strategy(score=0, opponent_score=0)

Can someone help me debug these? Thank you!

Here is the function:

```
def always_roll(n):
    """Return a strategy that always rolls N dice.
    A strategy is a function that takes two total scores as arguments (the
    current player's score, and the opponent's score), and returns a number of
    dice that the current player will roll this turn.
    >>> strategy = always_roll(5)
    >>> strategy(0, 0)
    5
    >>> strategy(99, 99)
    5
    """
    def strategy(score, opponent_score):
        return n
    return strategy()
```

Here is the doctest result:

```
Failed example:
    strategy = always_roll(5)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/doctest.py", line 1351, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest always_roll.always_roll[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        strategy = always_roll(5)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/always_roll.py", line 14, in always_roll
        return strategy()
               ^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: always_roll.<locals>.strategy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'score' and 'opponent_score'
**********************************************************************
File "/Users/always_roll.py", line 7, in always_roll.always_roll
Failed example:
    strategy(0, 0)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/doctest.py", line 1351, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest always_roll.always_roll[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        strategy(0, 0)
        ^^^^^^^^
    NameError: name 'strategy' is not defined
**********************************************************************
File "/Users/always_roll.py", line 9, in always_roll.always_roll
Failed example:
    strategy(99, 99)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/doctest.py", line 1351, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest always_roll.always_roll[2]>", line 1, in <module>
        strategy(99, 99)
        ^^^^^^^^
    NameError: name 'strategy' is not defined
```

I try setting default value for strategy(score=0, opponent_score=0) but that didn't help either

Comment: In your example, function `strategy` does not use `score` and `opponent_score`, so why have them as parameters?

Comment: I think you want to `return strategy`, i.e. return the function, not call it. No parentheses!

Comment: the function `strategy()` is expecting 2 arguments, `score`, `opponent_score`....  but the code calls it with None.